# Super huge bottleneck writing to GPU Compute Buffer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I am making a compute shader in Unity but the issue is I have a super huge bottleneck in my code where I am basically losing 1000x performance.

I have created some example code to demonstrate the problem, the function of the code is non relevant and doesn't make super much sense.

I lose a silly amount of performance writing to the compute buffer `cBuffer[id].vel += vel;` (*in shader code*) with that line enabled I get about 40fps in unity with the `pCount = (1024 * 256);` ~256k (*in c# code*) but if I disable the write to buffer line in the shader I can do `pCount = (1024 * 1024 * 64);` ~64m at > 60fps, no problem. I guess its because the different threads try to write to the same memory and have to wait for other threads to finish, but is there any way to do this in a more clever way?

**[Download Unity and Visual Studio Project files](http://www.patan77.com/download/computeShaderPerformance.zip)** *(unity 2017.3.0f3)*

**C# CODE:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class computeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ComputeShader cShader;

    struct Particle
    {
        public Vector2 pos;
        public Vector2 vel;
    }

    ComputeBuffer cBuffer;
    const int pCount = (1024 * 256); // <--- set count
    Particle[] particles = new Particle[pCount];
    int kernelCSMain;

    void Start ()
    {
        kernelCSMain = cShader.FindKernel("CSMain");
        cShader.SetInt("pCount", pCount);

        cBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(pCount, (sizeof(float) * 4), ComputeBufferType.Default);

        for(int i = 0; i < pCount; i++)
        {
            particles[i] = new Particle();
            particles[i].pos = new Vector2();
            particles[i].vel = new Vector2();
        }
            cBuffer.SetData(particles);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        cShader.SetBuffer(kernelCSMain, "cBuffer", cBuffer);
        cShader.Dispatch(kernelCSMain, pCount / 1024, 1, 1);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        cBuffer.Release();
    }
}
```

**Compute Shader CODE:**

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

struct Particle
{
    float2 pos;
    float2 vel;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<Particle> cBuffer;
int pCount;

[numthreads(1024,1,1)]
void CSMain (uint id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    float2 vel;
    for (int i = 0; i < pCount; i++) 
    {
        vel += (cBuffer[id].pos + cBuffer[i].pos);
    }
    cBuffer[id].vel += vel; // <---- this line is the issue
}
```

Comment: Well, your for-loop that assigns a value to vel (`vel = (cBuffer[id].pos + cBuffer[i].pos);`) may as well not exist: you overwrite the value with the next one. You could just grab the *last* value in the cBuffer and use it. Unless you meant to *add* all those values together.

Comment: Have you tried caching cBuffer[id] in the beginning of the loop rather than loading it every time in the loop?

Comment: @Draco18s that's just a a typo in this code that I put together as an example should be "+=" just "=" yeah would be really dumb.

Comment: @bashrc good suggestion I should be doing that instead, but unfortunately no visible performance difference, its not even the += that's the problem with  cBuffer[id].vel changing it to cBuffer[id].vel = 1, still same performance problem , the writing slows down everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem does not come from the write, the problem comes from dead code elimination.

If I takes your code, without the write:

```
[numthreads(1024,1,1)]
void CSMain (uint id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    float2 vel;
    for (int i = 0; i < pCount; i++) 
    {
        vel += (cBuffer[id].pos + cBuffer[i].pos);
    }
}
```

The compiler will detect that vel is not used anywhere (as per, not written), so will remove code that is assigning it.
Then since the line :

```
vel += (cBuffer[id].pos + cBuffer[i].pos);
```

is removed (as vel is not used), the compiler detects that the loop content is now empty, so also gets rid of the loop.

So in your case, commenting the line ends up with an empty shader that does nothing.

To demonstrate it, Here is the result by compiling your shader using fxc:

```
fxc cs.fx /O3 /Tcs_5_0 /ECSMain
```

First with the write enabled:

```
cs_5_0
dcl_globalFlags refactoringAllowed
dcl_constantbuffer CB0[1], immediateIndexed
dcl_uav_structured u0, 16
dcl_input vThreadID.x
dcl_temps 2
dcl_thread_group 1024, 1, 1
ld_structured_indexable(structured_buffer, stride=16)
(mixed,mixed,mixed,mixed) r0.xy, vThreadID.x, l(0), u0.xyxx
mov r0.zw, l(0,0,0,0)
mov r1.x, l(0)
loop
  ige r1.y, r1.x, cb0[0].x
  breakc_nz r1.y
  ld_structured_indexable(structured_buffer, stride=16)
  (mixed,mixed,mixed,mixed) r1.yz, r1.x, l(0), u0.xxyx
  add r1.yz, r0.xxyx, r1.yyzy
  add r0.zw, r0.zzzw, r1.yyyz
  iadd r1.x, r1.x, l(1)
endloop
ld_structured_indexable(structured_buffer, stride=16)
(mixed,mixed,mixed,mixed) r0.xy, vThreadID.x, l(8), u0.xyxx
add r0.xy, r0.zwzz, r0.xyxx
store_structured u0.xy, vThreadID.x, l(8), r0.xyxx
ret
// Approximately 15 instruction slots used
```

Now if you comment your write and run the same compile task:

```
cs_5_0
dcl_globalFlags refactoringAllowed
dcl_thread_group 1024, 1, 1
ret
// Approximately 1 instruction slots used
```

Also, please note that in your case you are running an n^2 algorithm in compute, each of your particle performs a check against each other (for each 262144 of them), you are performing 68719476736 "iterations" (which explains the drastic loss of performances as soon as the write is enabled)